# A question in Artin's Algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In chapter 7-More group Theory, section 7.5 Conjugation in the symmetric Group Proposition 7.5.1 :Two permutations p and p' are conjugate elements of the symmetric group if and only if their cycle decomposition have the same orders.
What is the meaning of "cycle decomposition",and the meaning of "order" here?
Please show me examples. Thanks!

Comment: These terms are defined elsewhere in the book: try the index.

Comment: Sorry, I have try to find them out, but the cycle decomposition is not in the index and previous chapters.

Comment: @Curran google definitely has that!

Comment: In the index: "Cycle notation, 24"

Comment: Very Sorry, I cannot find cycle "decomposition" in page 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cycle decomposition of permutation $p$ is $p = (12)\circ (34) \circ \dots \circ (576)$ for example.  Each $(abc\dots z)$ that you see is called a cylce permutation, that is defined to be $f(a) = b, f(b) = c, \dots, f(y) = z, f(z) = a$ (see how it wraps around?).  I believe in a cycle decomp, each cycle must be disjoint from the others.  Then count the number of cycles, that number should stay constant across all possible disjoint cycle decompositions I presume, and they call that the *order*.

Let $p$ be a permutation, of finitely or countably infinitely many items, e.g. of the sequence $(1,2,3)$ or even $(1,2, \dots)$.

For each $n$ in your sequence compute iterates of $p$, for example with $n=1$: $1, p(1), p\circ p(1), p^3(1), p^4(1), \dots \ $ If your sequence is finite, prove that these iterates repeat.  Create a cycle from this list of iterations as it does indeed specify a cycle in the decomp of $p$.  For each new element in your sequence that you come across in writing down the iterates for $1$ (for instance), remove that from your collection of sequence elements that you're processing.  For example say $p(1) = 2, \ p(2) = 1$.  Then the cycle would be $(1 2)$ and you've met $2$ already, so you don't have to visit that one as it would result in the same cycle $(21) = (12)$.  So if there's a $3$ in your sequence, and you haven't seen it yet, do iterations on it: $3, p(3), p^2(3), \dots$.  To get another cycle in the decomp.  Continue doing that until you've hit all elements in your sequence.

Thusly you can decompose any permutation into a composition of disjoint cycles.  For an infinite sequence and infinitely-specified permuation, you might get an infinite composition of disjoint cycles.

For the above to be true we should say that for infinite sequences, a cycle is defined to be either a finite cycle or of the form: $a \to b \to c \to \dots $ (ie with no wrap around).

Comment: Thank you, but I think the length of each cycle must be the same.

Comment: @Curran not the case.  Take $(12)(345)$.  If you mean the transposition decomp, then yes, that's a cycle-decomp into strictly $2$-cycles aka transpositions.  I believe what you want is the *disjoint* decomposition and that guarantees that you cant decomp into further cycles as the cycles would then not be disjoint, otherwise the certain cycle you're decomping further wasn't a cycle to begin as a cycle *simply cannot be decomposed further into more, disjoint cycles*.  I've done a proof of these statements before, let me know if you want me to sketch it out.

Comment: @Curran I added a bunch to the post.  That's the basic proof work involved in checking some of the above statements.

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm! Sorry, I think I did't speak clearly. I mean that if a and b are conjugate elements, then in their cycle decompositions, the corresponding pair must have the same length.